# SASS watch multiple .scss in sub-dir of directory select?

Tags: sass, watch

I start a project where I have this : [Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axnk3.png)

And I like to do something like this :

: sass --watch Component/*.scss:css/style.css

When a save is done in any .scss in Component/, it run "watch", is that possible ?

Thk for looking;

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the sass gem you have the following options:

`update` will compile a single file or multiple files in a folder (depending on the parameters). `watch` will do the same and after the initial compilation is completed it will watch the file or all the files in the specified folder, so everytime a change is detected on any of the target files, `sass` will compile the changed ones.

Both options have the same command line sintax:

```
sass --watch input/folder:output/folder
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

So, to compile all the files in a folder:

```
sass --update path/to/input/folder:path/to/output/folder
```

And to compile and then watch a folder:

```
sass --watch path/to/input/folder:path/to/output/folder
```

Just run `sass --help` for a complete list of options.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

Supposing, you use gulp to run the tasks.

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass'); //after npm i gulp-sass --save-dev in your terminal.

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('./app/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);  //place the correct location of your scss folder
});
```

And include watch in 'build' task

```
// *** build task *** //
gulp.task('build', function() {
  runSequence(
    ['watch']
  );
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I use gem instead gulp, so i hope that hack work with it too. Thk a lot for your answers.